# Formatar resultado de tempo

Tags: mysql

Tenho os seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de formatar o resultado da minha seguinte Query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(primeiraSaida, primeiraEntrada) + TIMEDIFF(segundaSaida, segundaEntrada)
FROM pontoentradasaida 
WHERE primeiraEntrada BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14';
```

Onde a saída está sendo essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas que gostaria que saísse: H:mm:ss ou 8:59:68s Ou 9:00:08

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, acontece que não tem como converter em hora dessa forma que você fez, visto que a função `TIMEDIFF` retorna já no formato `H:i:s`.

Daí quando você usa o operador + para somar, não é mais um campo do tipo DATE ou TIME.

Por isso temos que fazer algumas conversões. A diferença de tempo tem que ser convertida em segundos e depois somada. E por último convertida em formato de tempo de novo.

```
SEC_TO_TIME ( SUM ( TIME_TO_SEC ( TIMEDIFF ) + TIME_TO_SEC ( TIMEDIFF ) ) )
```

### **SQL**

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        SUM(
            TIME_TO_SEC(
                TIMEDIFF(
                    primeiraSaida,
                    primeiraEntrada
                )
            ) + TIME_TO_SEC(
                TIMEDIFF(
                    segundaSaida,
                    segundaEntrada
                )
            )
        )
    )
FROM
    pontoentradasaida
WHERE
    primeiraEntrada BETWEEN '2018-09-13'
AND '2018-09-14';
```

Comment: Tentei, mas o valor está retornando null

Comment: Corrigida a resposta.

Comment: show, deu certo. muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar usar a função [`TIME_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format):

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(
  TIMEDIFF(primeiraSaida, primeiraEntrada) + TIMEDIFF(segundaSaida, segundaEntrada))
  , '%H:%i') AS DIFERENCA
```

Comment: Tentei, mas o valor está retornando null